# Adding a node.js applications as an Apache Alias?

Tags: node.js, tomcat, apache2, integration

When connecting Apache Tomcat web-apps to an existing Apache website, mod_jk can be loaded to give a web application an Alias within Apache.

Are there any similar modules for connecting node.js to Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [answer here](http://arguments.callee.info/2010/04/20/running-apache-and-node-js-together/) and tested it out on my own local webserver.

Just like @othiym23 said you have to use Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to make it work.

You can add a relatively simple rule to your .htaccess file like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^tiddlywiki5.*$ http://whereNodeDotJSIsRunning:8080/ [P]


</IfModule>
```

And this will yield a URL like `http://yourApacheServer.com/tiddlywiki5/` from which you can visit your node.js server through Apache2.  The `[P]` flag at the end of the rule is used to  forward the request to a different server via [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) and return it to the user as though they were visiting `http://yourApacheServer.com/tiddlywiki5/`

Answer (score 2):

Node isn't an application server, like Tomcat. It's a native network / web server in its own right (and which runs as its own independent process), so if you want to connect Apache to a Node application, it's easiest simply to use Apache's [built-in proxy support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

In most circumstances, it's probably more efficient to have Node act as the web server on its own, as its HTTP support is complete and efficient. There are many web frameworks for it, like [Express](http://expressjs.com/), Strata or RESTify, and also middleware libraries that handle things like efficiently serving static resources.

Answer (score 0):

Plesk has an extension for Node now. It's seamless, has wide range of features and free: http://ext.plesk.com/packages/28f799af-1ff4-4bb8-9c87-a04f0f23d32e-jxcore-support